# How to search a sub string into a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to search products using any keyword.

I have a JSON file with very large data I have converted it in array using `json_decode()`. I am able to display all data but I want to search inside it for particular product. With or without regular expression, can you please suggest me a algorithm to do that?

Comment: How does your JSON look a like? And what do you want to search in it?

Comment: post your array

Comment: this is the array      https://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=0c3eb906f332562de73dafb0b9bb74e0ca0e1c0d4558de91132c0abadd024da2

Comment: My key word may look like 'airtel offer' or  '10% off on clothing  ' or may be much like these

Answer (score 0):

To search an array you can use `in_array()`, which will search through the values and returns `true` if it finds the value.
If the string you're looking for is a key/index in the array, then you can use `array_key_exists()`. Though, in your case it sounds like you're looking for a value.

Another tip, and a personal favorite of mine, is an alternative to `array_key_exists()`. If you have an array with short and specific values, say a list of car manufacturers, then you can invert the array and simply test if the key is set.
Something like this, in other words:

```
$makers = ['BMW', 'Toyota', 'Koenigsegg');
$makers = array_flip ($makers);
if (isset ($makers[$check])) {
    echo "Found!";
}
```

Note that this approach is only generally useful in edge-cases, as normally you'd pass the index instead of the value and simply test against it.

Comment: my JSON file look like    https://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=0c3eb906f332562de73dafb0b9bb74e0ca0e1c0d4558de91132c0abadd024da2

Comment: My key word may look like 'airtel offer' or  '10% off on clothing  ' or may be much like these

Comment: Then the `in_array()` approach is the correct one for you.

Answer (score -1):

It is pretty simple, lets say you have an array like this.

```
<?php
  $myArray = array(
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "cat"
  )
?>
```

To search to see if one exists use the array_key_exists function.
For example:

```
<?php
  $myArray = array(
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "cat"
  )
  if (array_key_exists("foo", $myArray)) {
    echo "Foo does exist";
  }
?>
```

the if statement will say Foo does exist because it is in the array.

the same thing works with these types of arrays too.

```
<?php
  $myArray = array(
    "foo" => "a",
    "bar" => "s",
    "cat" => "d"
  )
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_key_exists.asp

Comment: This won't work for the first case, as `"foo"` isn't the key. The key for the _value_ `foo` is `0`. You need to use `in_array()` for this. The last example is correct though, as `foo` is the key in that case.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to re-read the PHP manual, or test your own example code: http://codepad.org/mUGDifHL

Comment: My key word may look like 'airtel offer' or  '10% off on clothing  ' or may be much like these

Comment: my JSON file look like      https://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=0c3eb906f332562de73dafb0b9bb74e0ca0e1c0d4558de91132c0abadd024da2